# Modifying global variable from within function that have the same parameter name in python

Tags: function, python-3.x, global-variables

I have this function:

```
def applychange(L):
    result=3+2
    L=[4,5,6]
    return result
L = [1,2,3]
print(applychange(L))
print(L)
```

and the result is :

```
5
[1, 2, 3]
```

how to change the `L` variable to new value to have this result:

```
5
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to modify `L` as global variable you need to declare it as such.
For your code to run as intended, insert `global L` after the `result` assignment in your function.
Additionally, there is no need to pass `L` to the function in order to modify `L`.

```
def applychange():
    result = 3 + 2
    global L
    L = [4, 5, 6]
    return result

L = [1, 2, 3]
print(applychange())
print(L)
```

Your code written this way will result in the intended output:

```
5
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you overwrite the variable `L`, instead of modifying it. You can use

```
L[:] = [4,5,6]
```

instead of

```
L = [4,5,6]
```